# Does expo break the rules of the itunes store?

Tags: ios, expo

## Background

I've been working on a react native app that uses expo to build and deploy the application to both stores.

Today I came across quite an amazing feature in expo. The publish button inside the gui actually pushes all of the changes you have made to every user of your app. There is no need for building and jumping through all of the hoops that Apple & Google makes you do.

## Question

Since these changes can be basically full new versions of the app and no one at Apple/Google has checked them does this break the terms of service with Apple? They cannot monitor your newest release changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with App Store and Google Play policies

Answer (score 0):

When choosing an app rating just set "unrestricted web acces" to true, that should be it